# Upload images to Google Cloud bucket in Angular 7 App

Tags: angular, google-cloud-storage

How do I upload an image to Google Cloud bucket in an Angular 7 App that does not use Node.js as the backed but uses Firebase (as a backend service)? 
I have checked for tutorials and documentation but I've not seen any that tackles using Angular specifically.

Is uploading images from Angular apps to Google Storage buckets an impossibility at the moment or is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have used AWS S3 pre-signed url to upload file directly from angular without any traffic going through the node.js server. its safe and you do not need a public bucket , it would work flawlessly with a private bucket with encryption and accelerations enabled.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try firestore instead
https://fireship.io/snippets/install-angularfire/